# Expo: Timeout of >expo start< for new projects

Tags: node.js, expo

I recognized today, when I create a new project with

> expo init *projectname*

that these fail to be previewed in app simulator with

> expo start

Former projects, I created months ago can still be previewed. I get the following message in VS Code Terminal for newer projects after timeout:

> Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit. Error:
> EMFILE: too many open files, watch
> at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:178:28)

I already uninstalled node.js and expo by these steps: https://dev.to/delightfullynerdy/uninstall-node-js-on-macos-big-sur-2hi8
But it didn't help. I am on MacOS BigSur but everything worked after migrating from former MacOS. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: you should install watchman - it's required to use expo-cli on macos https://docs.expo.io/get-started/installation/#1-expo-cli